# Can anybody explain me this code?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

```
aCCB->C16_ArgInfo(aCCB->InstHdl,2,&tType2,&tOpt2,&tLen2,NULL,&tCount2);

if (tType2 == _TypeAlpha &&
    tOpt2  == (_ArgOptVAR | _ArgOptARRAY))
{
    /* read array */
    tBuf = static_cast<char*>(malloc(tLen2));
    aCCB->C16_ArgRead(aCCB->InstHdl,2,0,tBuf);

    tTab  = static_cast<char**>(malloc(sizeof(char*) * tCount2));
    tSize = tLen2 / tCount2;
    *tTab = tBuf;

    /* define sort table */
    for (tLoop = 1; tLoop < tCount2; ++tLoop)
        tTab[tLoop] = tTab[tLoop-1] + tSize;
```

What I do understand is that aCCB->InstHdl contains some raw data that is converted into a string array (char**).

What I don't understand is the last loop. What does it do? What is it for? I have to admit that my C++ knowledge is quite nonexistant...

Comment: It's really difficult to say anything without knowing what those `C16_...` functions do.

Comment: This is a pretty specific question, so while you can reason the `tTab` will have a bunch of values, we won't be able to tell you what those numbers really mean. Also there is likely a bug with the line `tTab[tLoop] = tTab[tLoop-1] + tSize;` since `tTab` was `malloc`-allocated, so accessing `tTab[0]` will probably result in unexpected or undefined behavior, since the memory wasn't initialized.

Comment: Urgh. Looks like the cat's been on the keyboard again. And it's C cat, too, because it uses `malloc()`. Oh no, it's a bastard, because it also uses `static_cast<>`. And did I mention the code is ugly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It loops through the array, assigning the value of the previous iteration plus tSize.  What that means or why...how the hell should I know?

I wouldn't be too hard on yourself for not being able to make sense of that code.  It's very hard to read.

Edit:

Oh man.  Just read one of the comments to the OP and looked at it some more.  This code is HORRIBLE!!!

Here's what seems to be happening:
An array is read into tBuf.
An array of arrays is then created to hold tCount2 arrays.
tSize is then initialized to tLen2/tCount2, which creates basically tCount2 items...you'll see.

Then the tBuf pointer is assigned to the first element in the tTab 'array of arrays'.

Now the for loop....the for loop basically splits up the first element in the series and provides points into the main tBuf at each tLen2/tCount2 segment.

What you get is...

```
[0] [1] [2] [3] [4]
 |   |   |   |   |
 v   v   v   v   v
|datadatadatadatadata|
```

UGH!!!

And no, it doesn't cause any undefined or unspecified behavior.  It's just really f'n ugly.

Comment: An, now I get it. Stupid pointer manipulation.. Can you show me a sane way how to split the data from 'aCCB->InstHdl' into an array<String^>? (Managed C++)

Comment: I don't do managed c++.  You could *split* the sections into strings though with `std::string(tab[0], tab[1])`.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it looks like the loop sets `tTab` to successive substrings of the contents of `tBuf`, each shorter than the previous by length `tSize`. It doesn't split the substrings, but only sets up indexes into `tBuf`.

But without knowing what any of the `C16_*` functions do, I can't being to guess at the rest.